# How do I add a delay after a player triggers an event?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-development

How do I add a delay after a player triggers a jump, so that jumping cannot be triggered too frequently (or spammed)?

```
func jumpRight() {
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector (dx: 100, dy: 500))  
}

func jumpLeft() {
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector (dx: -100, dy: 500))    
}
```

Comment: I suggest to perform a check when the frame is updated, manage a bool and after 60 frames or whatever you want, change the boolean status to able the user to push it again

Comment: Exactly as mentioned in an answer

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is by using a Boolean flag which changes when the player triggers a jump and is automatically reset after a short delay.

```
var canJump: Bool = True

func jumpRight() {
    guard canJump == True else { return }
    self.canJump = False
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector (dx: 100, dy: 500))
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.2) {
        self.canJump = True
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats Ok but really a dispatch queue from inside a game loop ?  what happens when applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) occurs. Is the dispatch queue nicely handled

Comment: @hoboBob This is not triggered on a game loop but by user interaction (i.e. when the user makes the sprite *jump*).

Comment: its inside the game loop. you called it from inside the game loop to act on something inside the game loop. Time will have no variance to the physical play of the game. Propagation delay. where will it end up ! Also DispatchQueue and applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) are never going to play nice together.

Comment: @hoboBob True. Is it that the dispatch queue might get cancelled if the app goes into the background? I hadn’t considered that I have to admit. I guess it could leave the game in an indeterminate state when coming to the foreground again.

Comment: There are other problems beyond what hoboBob is saying.  What if you decide to pause your game?  That dispatch will still fire.  You should avoid any timing mechanisms that are outside of SpriteKit.  You should also sparingly use the currentTime from the update loop, because that is going off of the `SKView’s CADisplayLink.targetTimestamp`,  which means you will eventually have to handle syncing your delta time whenever a system event occurs that will lag this. Exploiting this is actually a great way to cheat in some indie games.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, wherever you have your jump button set, the target that it is selected (be it right jump or left jump) you need to add in a check that monitors when the jump command is pressed and when the jump command finishes.

I would start by adding a completion handler on your function.

```
func jumpRight(arg: Bool, completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
    completion(arg) 
}
```

By doing so you are identifying when the function finishes. 
Below is where you are calling the jump button command. Wherever you have the action defined you should call this.

```
jumpRight(arg: true, completion: { (success) -> Void in
    print("Second line of code executed")
    if success { // this will be equal to whatever value is set in this method call
          print("true")
    } else {
         print("false")
    }
})
```

If the individual has spammed jump the 'false' will print from the completion handler. That is where you prevent the user from jumping again until the action is completed as the function defines.

Answer (score -1):

1) I would determine what ground is and only jump when on ground.

```
func jumpRight() {
    if onGround == false {return}
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector (dx: 100, dy: 500))  
}

func jumpLeft() {
    if onGround == false {return}
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector (dx: -100, dy: 500))    
}
```

onGround could be a check if a physics body exists below the feet of a player, or it could be a specific y area, that is on you.

I would prefer to check for a body.

`rayStart` is where your "foot" would be

```
func isStandingOnGround(_ rayStart:CGPoint) -> Bool {
    let rayEnd = CGPoint(x: rayStart.x, y: rayStart.y + 1) // + 1 is distance to ground,  change it if a wider gap is needed.
    let body = scene.physicsWorld.body(alongRayStart: rayStart, end: rayEnd)
    return (body?.categoryBitMask ?? 0) & Category.Ground > 0
}
```

2) If you need to add a "recharge", (This would be where a "delay" between jumps happens for those who do not understand game mechanics)  I would use SKActions

```
func jumpRight() {
    if onGround == false || player.action(forKey:"jump") {return}
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector (dx: 100, dy: 500))  
    player.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration:1), withKey:"jump")
}

func jumpLeft() {
    if onGround == false || player.action(forKey:"jump") {return}
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector (dx: -100, dy: 500))    
    player.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration:1), withKey:"jump")
}
```

3) To be on the safe side, also include that velocity of y is zero (or some threshold that does not signify a jump)

```
func jumpRight() {
    if onGround == false || player.action(forKey:"jump") || player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy != 0 {return}
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector (dx: 100, dy: 500))  
    player.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration:1), withKey:"jump")
}

func jumpLeft() {
    if onGround == false || player.action(forKey:"jump") || player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy != 0 {return}
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector (dx: -100, dy: 500))    
    player.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration:1), withKey:"jump")
}
```

Because a particular person is having a hard time with Sprite Kit,  I will post an exact answer to the very specific problem since they are unable to infer it.  I do not recommend doing only this when it comes to jumping, because it allows for double jumping or a jump when falling.

```
if !player.action(forKey:"jump”){
    player.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration:1), withKey:"jump")
    // insert your jump function calls here
}
```

You can use this technique for any kind or recharging.

You can even take it one step further and replace `wait` with `customActionWithDuration` or `sequence` \ `group` to create animations to go along with the recharge time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204459/discussion-on-answer-by-knight0fdragon-how-do-i-add-a-delay-after-a-player-trigg).

Answer (score -2):

My solution would be to try something like this

```
var lastUpdateTime: TimeInterval = 0
var dt: TimeInterval = 0
let jumpHysterisisTimeLimit: TimeInterval = 0.2
var jumpHysterisisTimer: TimeInterval = 0
var jumpAGoGo: Bool = false

func updateGameLoopTimer(currentTime: TimeInterval) {
  if lastUpdateTime > 0 {
    dt = currentTime - lastUpdateTime
  } else {
    dt = 0
  }
  lastUpdateTime = currentTime
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    updateGameLoopTimer(currentTime: currentTime)
    isJumpAGoGo()
}

func isJumpAGoGo() {
  if jumpAGoGo {
    jumpHysterisisTimer += dt
    if jumpHysterisisTimer >= jumpHysterisisTimeLimit {
      jumpHysterisisTimer = 0
      jumpAGoGo = false
    }
  }
}

func jumpRight() {
  if !jumpAGoGo {
    jumpAGoGo = true
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector (dx: 100, dy: 500))
  }  
}

func jumpLeft() {
  if !jumpAGoGo {
    jumpAGoGo = true
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector (dx: -100, dy: 500)) 
  }
}
```

You can then play around with the *jumpHysterisisTimeLimit* value to suit what you want.